# React-select - I can not work out how to set a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

This has been asked quite a few times, so sorry, but I can't work this out. I hae read the docs, but I couldn't find anything that worked, so I obvioulsy don't understand what's happening here.

```
class DivisionExtraDetails extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        error: false,
        loading: true,
        removing: null,
        saving: false,
        geofence: false,
        startTimeOfDay: ''
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { division } = this.props;

    Axios.get(`${API_URL}assetgroups/${division.id}`)
        .then(r => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                geofence: r.data.geofence_assign,
                startTimeOfDay: r.data.day_start
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (!Axios.isCancel(err)) {
                this.setState({
                    error: true
                });
            }
    });
}


render() {
    const { error, loading, geofence, saving, startTimeOfDay } = this.state;
    const { assignText, division } = this.props;

    const geoFenceOptions = [
        {value: 1, label: 'YES'},
        {value: 0, label: 'NO'},
        {value: null, label: 'Not yet set'},
    ];

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="col-5">
             <span>Assign a GeoFence (Yes/No)</span>
               <Select
                 selectedValue={geofence}
                 options={geoFenceOptions}
                 className="basic-multi-select"
                 classNamePrefix="select"
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
            </div>                       
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

I've also tried:

```
defaultValue={geofence}
selectedValue={geofence}
value={geofence}
```

And I've also tried the variable as:

```
{this.state.geofence}
```

I can see the call to the db is correctly populating the state if I view it in dev tools.
But I can't work it out. If anyone can help with this seemingly simple task, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: can you let us know console log of `geofence`?

Comment: Returns 'false'

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect the different value name

const geoFenceOptions = [
            {value: true, label: 'Yes'},
            {value: false, label: 'N0'},
            {value: null, label: 'Not yet set'},
        ];

Comment: So you are passing options as objects but you are passing `value` in react select as boolean or string so that's why it is not working. Try to pass value as object like  `{value: false, label: 'N0'}`

Comment: Thank you very much. How might that value look if I am trying to dynamically populate that based on the API call? ---- {{value: {geofence}, label: {???}}}. <-- something like this?

Comment: you can create small function which will return object based on value from api call. in that function you can use switch case to check and return correct object value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `value` as boolean or string in react select but you are passing objects as it's options so that's why react select was not able to find show default value.

To Solve this you need to pass correct object in `value` prop so try something like below:-

```js
class DivisionExtraDetails extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        error: false,
        loading: true,
        removing: null,
        saving: false,
        geofence: false,
        startTimeOfDay: '',
       
       // set geoFenceOptions as state so we can use it later
       geoFenceOptions: [
        {value: true, label: 'YES'},
        {value: false, label: 'NO'},
        {value: null, label: 'Not yet set'},
       ];
    };
}


// find correct geoFenseOption based on provided value
getGeoFenceValue = (value) => {
  return this.state.geoFenceOptions.find(option => option.value === value);
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { division } = this.props;

    Axios.get(`${API_URL}assetgroups/${division.id}`)
        .then(r => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                geofence: this.getGeoFenceValue(r.data.geofence_assign),  // call function to find correct option
                startTimeOfDay: r.data.day_start
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (!Axios.isCancel(err)) {
                this.setState({
                    error: true
                });
            }
    });
}


render() {
    const { error, loading, geofence, saving, startTimeOfDay, geoFenceOptions } = this.state;
    const { assignText, division } = this.props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="col-5">
             <span>Assign a GeoFence (Yes/No)</span>
               <Select
                 selectedValue={geofence}
                 options={geoFenceOptions}
                 className="basic-multi-select"
                 classNamePrefix="select"
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
            </div>                       
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you or your help. I appreciate it, but, I still cannot set the default value, it's still not showing the value from "geofence".

Comment: Are you passing `value` prop in react-select?

Comment: I am currently using "selectedValue={this.state.startTimeOfDay.value}" in the select box. If I call "this.state.starTimeOfDay.value" from the console, it returns: "00:00:00" which is exactly what I need, but I cannot get it to load on first render of the component. I wonder if there is a different property on the Select component I should use to set it from first render after the DB call from "componentDidMount" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    // ... code omitted
    geofence: /* set default value here */
  };
}
```

Comment: It's already been set there, as shown in the code above. Either way, I do an API call in 'componentDidMount()' that sets it to the correct value from the DB.

Comment: Your `geoFenceOptions` is an array of objects, while you give a default value of `boolean`. Obviously, that will never work. Not to mention the available values in `geoFenceOptions` are `1`, `0`, and `null`. There is no `false` here.